# ZPAQ usage vague information

Tags: compression

I was trying to test the compression algorithms in matt mahoney's web, but when I want to decompress a file, it only saves the first block.
It gives me the following instructions

```
"zpaqd v6.19 ZPAQ development tool, " __DATE__ "\n"
"To compress: zpaqd {a|c}[i|n|s|t]... config [arg]... archive files...\n"
"  a - append to existing archive.zpaq\n"
"  c - create new archive.zpaq\n"
"  i - don't save file sizes in comments\n"
"  n - don't save file names\n"
"  s - don't save SHA-1 checksums or test post-processor\n"
"  t - don't save header locator tag\n"
"  config.cfg with args $1...$9 - see libzpaq.h\n"
"To decompress:   zpaqd d archive [output [block [blocks [segments]]]]\n"
"To list:         zpaqd l archive\n"
"To run:          zpaqd r config [arg]... {h|p} [input [output]]\n"
"To trace:        zpaqd t config [arg]... {h|p} [N|xN]...\n"
"To compute SHA1: zpaqd s files...\n"
"See http://mattmahoney.net/zpaq/ for latest version\n"
```

Information about the file names and blocks is given to me but I don't have an idea on 
what does "[output [block [blocks [segments]]]]" means. I have been trying to decompress but I really haven't figured it out. I know this site isn't about particular programs, but in all the web I haven't found any information, and this is my last resource

Comment: I just wrote up a zpaq blog post that describes how to implement a grayscale compression module with zpaql: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post15_zpaql_grayscale/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `zpaq` to extract, not `zpaqd`.

`zpaq` (current version is 6.41) is a general purpose archiver. `zpaqd` is mainly a tool for developing and testing compression algorithms written in the ZPAQL language. However you can use it to compress and decompress a single file like this:

```
zpaqd c 3 archive.zpaq input
zpaqd d archive.zpaq output
```

Detailed specs are in the source code comments in zpaqd.cpp or zpaq.cpp. If you use zpaqd it helps to understand the archive format described in http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq202.pdf and the ZPAQL language described in libzpaq.h.